# Отправка письма чере phpmailer в контейнере docker с ssl-сертификатом

Tags: php, docker, ssl, phpmailer

Не работает отправка сообщения через PHPMailer в контейнере docker с ssl-сертификатом. Раньше сайт работал без докер-контейнеров на сборке LAMP и письма отправлялись нормально. Обычная смена порта на 587 не помогает

```
$message = "Письмо от пользователя";
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPOptions = 'ssl';
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = true; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("user@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Письмо от посетителя";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com');
```

При отправке через SMTPOptions и смене порта на 587 письмо доходит нормально, однако, это решение не рекомендуется в документации.

```
$message = "Письмо от пользователя";
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => true,
    'allow_self_signed' => false
    )
);
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = true; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("user@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Письмо от посетителя";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com');
```

Как пофиксить эту проблему? Или хотя бы в какую сторону копать.

UPD:
Прикрепляю скрин сообщения об ошибке:
[image: Информация при активном debug флаге phpmailer]

Comment: `mailq` что пишет в контейнере

Comment: mailq: Mail queue is empty.

Comment: Значит отправил, в mail.log есть что либо?

Comment: Прикрепил скрин с ошибкой

Comment: openssl установлен то в кантэйнере?

Comment: спасибо за ответы. пофиксил проблему добавив сертификаты с хостинга на контейнер.